# Jenkins: how to block a job based on results of another job?

Tags: jenkins, jobs

Job1 runs whenever code is delivered. 
Job2 runs three times per day.

These are independent, non-hierarchical jobs.

My requirement is to run Job2 only if Job1 results in SUCCESS or UNSTABLE.

---

I checked out BuildResultsTrigger. It's not working. 
Also, I'm aware of pipeline plugin but that'll be a long term goal.

For now, I need a quick way to allow Job2 to run, only if the last execution of Job1 was SUCCESS or UNSTABLE. Job2 can start, as long as it does not complete its build steps. If I can insert a build step to the beginning of Job2 to check Job1 result and somehow make the Job2 fail, that would work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use build triggers to achieve this task..you have many choice 1. triggers, 2.Multijob plugin, 3.  Build flow plugin

Comment: Hi Mahi, looks like you're going for chainged jobs with these ideas. I can't have that. Job2 has its own schedule that must be followed strictly. So no trigger from Job1.

Answer (score 0):

@user2984213 the easiest and fastest way would be to:

At the end of the job 1 create a file somewhere and call it like green_light.txt if job is successful. Otherwise - force remove the file.

Then at the start of the job 2 check the file existence.

Comment: Jan, you're thinking exactly what I'm thinking. Do you have an example to speed me up? I understand in Job1 post build action I'd need to retrieve build status and then on status condition force create or force delete the file.

Comment: Using the job logic in Jenkins you can define the file creation in job 1 as a last command. It won't be executed unless everything went fine before. If you can't use that, you may for example define a variable ISSUES=0 at the start of the build and then if anything fails - set it to 1. At the end check the variable status and if it is 1 - create the file, if it is 0 - attempt to delete the file, guarding the 'rm' from failing due to file inexistance.


In job 2 you may for example use:

    set +e; stat green_light.txt; if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then echo "job1 was failed, retreating..." exit 0 fi